# Is it possible to address child class properties after verifying a required inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am working with several child class with the same parent class. I'd like to give an object to a function that can be one of the child classes, then make a veryfication of the child class type and then I want to address the corresponding child class properties directly.

```
class human
{
    public string name;
}

class woman : human
{
    public bool isPregnant;
}

class man : human
{
    public int numberOfComputers;
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        man Andrew = new man();
    }

    public void checkHuman<T>(T my_human) where T : human
    {
        // is something like this possible??
        if (typeof(my_human).Name == "woman")
            Console.WriteLine(my_human.name & " is " & (my_human.isPregnant ? "pregnant." : "not pregnant."));
        if (typeof(my_human).Name == "man") {
            man m = (man)my_human;
            Console.WriteLine(m.name & " has " & m.numberOfComputers & " computers.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glossing over the Java-style naming conventions... in general, if you ever find yourself having to write custom logic based on the actual type of a generic variable, there's a good chance you're using generics wrong. But back to your question, yes, `typeof(T).Name` gets you the actual type that was passed in. `typeof` is a keyword reserved only for types not variables; so you can't run it on `my_human`. The equivalent would be `my_human.GetType().Name`

Comment: You should also look in to the `is` and `as` operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t really use generics there. Instead, you just want to accept any Human object (remember that `Man` and `Woman` are also valid `Human` objects) and use the `is` operator to check the concrete type:

```
public void CheckHuman(Human human)
{
    if (human is Woman)
    {
        var woman = (Woman)human;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}pregnant.", woman.Name, woman.IsPregnant ? "" : "not ");
    }
    else if (human is Man)
    {
        var man = (Man)human;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} computers.", man.Name, man.NumberOfComputers);
    }
}
```

You can als use C# 7 operater patterns here to automatically cast the object into the correct type:

```
public void CheckHuman(Human human)
{
    if (human is Woman woman)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}pregnant.", woman.Name, woman.IsPregnant ? "" : "not ");
    }
    else if (human is Man man)
    {
        // please keep in mind that women have computers too
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} computers.", man.Name, man.NumberOfComputers);
    }
}
```

Note that I adjusted the general naming of your types and members: Class names, methods and properties should all use PascalCase, while variables and fields use camelCase.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible to check the type of an object, cast to that type and access the child properties.  However doing this is a "smell" and indicates your abstraction isn't correct.

Instead you should define the common expected behaviour in your parent class and then implement it in each child class.  That way your calling code doesn't need to know the exact child class it is calling, and instead depends on the contract proposed by the parent class.

```
using System;

public abstract class Human
{
    public string Name;

    public abstract string GetDetails();
}

public class Woman : Human
{
    public bool IsPregnant;

    public override string GetDetails() 
    {
        return Name + " is " + (IsPregnant ? "pregnant." : "not pregnant.");
    }
}

public class Man : Human
{
    public int NumberOfComputers;

    public override string GetDetails() 
    {
        return Name + " has " + NumberOfComputers + " computers.";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var andrew = new Man 
        {
            Name = "Andrew",
            NumberOfComputers = 200
        };

        OutputDetails(andrew);
    }

    public static void OutputDetails(Human myHuman)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myHuman.GetDetails());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkHuman<T>(T my_human) where T : human
{

    var woman = my_human as woman;
    if (woman != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is {1}", woman.name, woman.isPregnant ? "pregnant." : "not pregnant."));
    }
    else
    {
        var man = my_human as man;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} has {1} computers", man.name, man.numberOfComputers));
    }
}
```